# Como mostrar la dirección ip y el proveedor de internet del lado del cliente?

Tags: nodejs, servidor, ip

Necesito mostrar la dirección ip y el proveedor de internet en una aplicacion node.js. El codigo que tengo hecho muestra los datos del servidor. Cuando esta local funciona obviamente porque mi servidor es mi misma pc. pero cuando lo subo a un servidor me muestra el proveedor de internet del servidor y yo quiero que muestre la del cliente que accede a la aplicacion

Acá está el codigo:

```
// Esta IP, para chequea si un cliente esta pegado a un vpn ?  
//https://nordvpn.com/api/vpn/check/full
var options_nord_check = {
host: 'nordvpn.com',           
path: '/api/vpn/check/full',
headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' },
agent: agent
};

function ObtenerDatosIsp(callback) {

https.get(options_nord_check, function (res) {

    var json = '';
    console.log('Isp ' + json)
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        json += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {

        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(json);
                console.log('Isp ' + data)
                return callback(null, data);
            } catch (e) {
                return callback(e);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            return callback(res.statusCode);
        }
    });
}).on('error', function (err) {
    return callback(err);
});
```

Comment: Hola Osleynin, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar el formato de tu pregunta, agrega lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola podes usar este modulo.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip

Saludos.